# Confusion about MVP pattern Android

Tags: android, architecture, mvp

I am experience Android Developer of almost 2.5 years, who was simple writing all codes in Activity class.

Recently I came across many good things about development that will make developer life awesome.

1. Retrofit
2. RxJava/RxAndroid
3. Dagger
4. MVP pattern
5. Testing code (Unit Test)

**What I learned (at least to start with project)**

1. Retrofit
2. RxJava/RxAndroid

**Whats my confusion about MVP**

There are people who follow the code style

- View (Interface)
- Presenter (Interface)
- PresenterImplementation (Class)
- Interactor (Interface)
- InteractorImplementation (Class)

But , I follow

- View (Interface)
- Presenter (Class) --- implements  --> [ PresenterForView (Interface) & PresenterForInteractor (Interface) ]
- PresenterForView (Interface) -- Its works for **View** (eg . login button clicked in **View i.e, Activity**) . Takes login click from **View** and gives to **Interactor**
- PresenterForInteractor (Interface) -- Its works for **Interactor** (eg . gets response from **Interactor** like success , failure to show in **View i.e, Activity**) .
- Interactor (Class) : does validation logics , calls webservice (Rxjava & Retrofit used) , **returns the NoNetwork,TimeOut,Failure, Success response to PresenterForInteractor**

Many people say that Logics (if..else) should only be written in **Interactor** . Your View(Activity) , Presenter should not contain (If else statement) app logic.

There many tutorials found on `Medium` in which people do anything .
They write half app logic in **Presenter** , rest in **Interactor**

I tried to follow the First Option of writing every app login in **Interactor**

But there are scenario where I get confused where to write app login

- onActivityResult
- onRequestPermission
- using data in 2nd Activity got from 1st Actiity via Intent.putExtras (which I always use in OnCreate() of 2nd Activity)

Comment: Could you post a link to those tutorials? All I can say for now is that MVP works totally fine without Interactors. So you don't have to worry if you don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

On two use cases,

> - onActivityResult
> - onRequestPermission

I distinguish logic in a way that, if that logic do anything on UI - **UI logic**(e.g: update Text, showing dialog, animation, etc.) is belong to the Activity/Fragment. Because you are just on that Activity/Fragment, then you may just call it right away.

If you need to operate any business logic, such as: update the database, network request/response, etc. You may need to call it via Presenter. E.g:

```
presenter.getDataFromTheWeb()
```

> - using data in 2nd Activity got from 1st Actiity via Intent.putExtras (which I always use in OnCreate() of 2nd Activity)

To retrieve data in Activity/Fragment uses **getArgument()**, which attached with its Activity/Fragment. So that you retrieve data in Activity class makes sense.

In overall, MVP is a great way to de-couple view logic/application logic and business logic, also helps you to test your app more easily. However using right pattern depends on particular problem you solve. If your business logic is also complex, you need Interactor pattern.